# Why negative times negative is positive?

Tags: arithmetic

I know that many people would say I don't even know this. But I know it very well that negative × neagtive = positive. But I don't know Why? So kindly give a logical answers.

Answer (score 1):

Debt is negative. If you take away someones debt, you would be practically giving them positive money.

Comment: http://mathforum.org/dr.math/faq/faq.negxneg.html Related link about the example grdgfgr gave.

Answer (score 0):

Mathematically, we define $\mathbb{R}$ to be an ordered field, which has this property (proposition 1.18 in baby Rudin). Intuitively, "negative"="opposite", and the opposite of the opposite is the same.

Comment: Good explanation!